# Raylib и raylib-cpp ошибка компиляции

Tags: c++, c, библиотеки

Установил raylib, взял готовый проект из папки raylib под code blocks, запустил, все работает.
Хочу добавить [raylib-cpp](https://github.com/RobLoach/raylib-cpp/tree/master), делаю все по инструкции, подключаю raylib-cpp.hpp
но при компиляции вылазит ошибка:

```
raylibexception.hpp|4|fatal error: stdexcept: No such file or directory|
```

Почему ?

BuildLog

```
-------------- Build: Debug (Windows) in raylib-game-template (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g  -c C:\Users\*****\Desktop\project\raylib\core_basic_window.c -o obj\Debug\core_basic_window.o
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe  -o bin\Debug\raylib-game-template.exe obj\Debug\core_basic_window.o  -static  -lraylib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -lpthread
In file included from c:\users\*****\desktop\project\raylib\include\audiodevice.hpp:6,
                 from C:\Users\*****\Desktop\project\raylib\include/raylib-cpp.hpp:34,
                 from C:\Users\*****\Desktop\project\raylib\core_basic_window.c:19:
c:\users\*****\desktop\project\raylib\include\raylibexception.hpp:4:10: fatal error: stdexcept: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <stdexcept>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Comment: Какой командой компилируете? Не говорите "по инструкции", говорите что конкретно делаете. Какая это ОС?

Comment: windows 10. Взял готовый проект из папки raylib под code blocks.Компилятор тот, что в комплекте с raylib

Comment: Содержимое build log покажите. Вы как-то выбирали компилятор в настройках CB?

Comment: Хочется не вывод из таблицы, а необработанный вывод компилятора. Где-то там есть такой, вроде вкладка называется build log.

Comment: `gcc` (у вас он называется `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe`) - это компилятор языка С. Для С++ нужен `g++` (`x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe`, видимо). Но где он у вас выбирается - хз.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо HolyBlackCat за подсказку!
Проблема была в компиляторе. gcc сменил на g++ и все заработало